# intValue() for huge Integer is throwing error

Tags: java, asn.1

I working on an asn file structuring.
My existing code is having data type as:

```
Fieldname::= INTEGER
```

As per my requirement, I changed it to:

```
Fieldname::= INTEGER --<HUGE>--
```

While parsing this value through java, I am using:

```
int intValue = Fieldname.intValue()
```

After changing datatype (huge integer) I am getting error:

```
Error:(750,121) java: cannot find symbol
Cannot resolve method 'intvalue'
```

This is issue with parser only. How to parse a string to huge int.

Comment: Your error is showing that you are calling a method which does not exist. This does not look like a parsing error.

Comment: @jnrdn0011 When I was using datatype as integer then I was not getting any calling method error. Only after changing it to huge integer I am getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue.
I have used below code to parse the value in my java code.

```
BigInteger intValue = Fieldname.bigIntegerValue()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what tooling you are using.

EDIT: from your comment, I understand you are using OSS Nokalva. This is a commercial product and you should seek support from there.

However, this seems quite normal

The `--<HUGE>--` is a hint (pragma) for your code generator to use something bigger than an `int` in your java code. 
(Note that, as far as asn.1 is concerned, it is just a comment).

Hence, the accessor will be different: `longValue()` or  `bitIntegerValue()` or whatever your doc says.

Have a look at the generated code, you'll find it easily

Comment: With integer I was getting decoding issue. --<HUGE>-- is not hint. I have added it to parse larger values. I am using oss nokalva tool where asn file (with HUGE) is compiling well. But in my java code I am facing issue.